# NULL check in HIVE

Tags: hadoop, hive

I came across a strange behavior in my hive queries. While inserting values based on an input parameter I set an attribute to NULL. When I execute count

```
select count(id) from hive_table where val1 is NULL;
```

I get 0 as result. But I know there are around ~7.5 K records which has been set to NULL. Whereas the following query returns accurate result

```
select count(id) from hive_table where trim(val1) is NULL;
```

I am using Apache Hive version 1.2 and Hortonworks Hadoop 2.7. Any ideas why this is happening.

Comment: how did you insert NULL? You said "I set an attribute to NULL.", pls show us this code.

Comment: NULL as val1,
...

Answer (score 2):

`count` ignores `null` values which is why you get `0` as output. You should be counting rows instead.

```
select count(*) from hive_table where val1 is NULL;
```

Edit: I suppose you interpret empty strings as `null`s. Try this to check.

```
select sum(cast(trim(val1)='' as int)) as empty_str_count
,sum(cast(val1 is null as int)) as null_count
from hive_table
```

Comment: Actually the count was on id which is not null. My bad missed in the first edit.

Answer (score 1):

you can try another way to find Null records count from hive,

```
select count(id) from hive_table where length(val1)=0;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why the second works.  But if you want to count `NULL` values, use:

```
select count(*)
from hive_table
where val1 is NULL;
```